# Angular 6: Change background color of div according to active tab

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to change the background color of class `tabswitch` on the basis of `tab1` and `tab2` active. I am doing this code on Angular 6.

```
<div class="tabswitch">
  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">tab1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">tab2</label>
  <div id="content1">b</div>
  <div id="content2">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use my logic, you should declare a variable named `activeTab` in your component and keep activated tab name inside of that variable and then you can use `[ngStyle]` directive to achieve this,

```
<div class="tabswitch" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': activeTab === 'tab1' ? 'green' : 'red' }">
  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">tab1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">tab2</label>
  <div id="content1">b</div>
  <div id="content2">a</div>
</div>
```

More examples are [here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/).

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="tabswitch" ng-class="active">
<input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" ng-click="active='tab1c'" checked>
<label for="tab1">tab1</label>
<input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs" ng-click="active='tab2c'">
<label for="tab2">tab2</label>
<div id="content1">b</div>
<div id="content2">a</div>
</div>
```

make css for class tab1c and tab2c

Comment: ng-click directive is for AngularJS, this question is about Angular6. This is not a proper answer.